# Get custom attribute label from value in Magento

Tags: magento

I need to get a custom attribute label from it's value.  I have the code below-

```
$labels = $product->getAdwordsLabels();
$labels_array = explode(',', $labels);
foreach($labels_array as $value) {
  $goog_labels .= "<g:adwords_labels>$value</g:adwords_labels>";
}
return $goog_labels;
```

The value of $value is the integer representation of the attribute.  I need the label of said attribute where $value is now.

How?

Comment: $product->getData('attribute_code');

Comment: I use it in this format - $this->getProduct()->getData('attribute_code');

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
    //$labels = $product->getAdwordsLabels();
    $labels = $product->getResource()->getAttribute("adwords_labels")->getStoreLabel();
    $labels_array = explode(',', $labels);
    foreach($labels_array as $value) {
      $goog_labels .= "<g:adwords_labels>$value</g:adwords_labels>";
    }
    return $goog_labels;
```